# surrogate keys vs compound keys

Tags: sql, database, sqlite, database-schema

Fairly new to database schema (plan to use SQLite).  Having said that, I'm thinking about using surrogate keys because the database currently contains a compound key (3 columns), which shows up in most of my tables.  I have several tables that contains 3 columns for the unique key and one column containing some information; I also have one table contains 3 column for unique key and the same 3 columns as foreign keys (many parents).  Combining all these tables into a single table doesn't seem to make sense because there would be many empty fields.

Any pit falls if I choose one or the other?  Which one is generally considered more convenient for programming?

Thank you in advance.

Comment: "3 columns for the unique key" -- The same 3 columns?  That sounds like poor schema design.  Merge the tables together.  `NULLs` are less of a problem than messy `LEFT JOINs`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Each technique has advantages and disadvantages.

In general, it's easier to write SQL statements and JOINs if you only need to refer to the single surrogate key column.  It also reduces the size of your database fairly substantially.

On the other hand, with surrogate keys you often find yourself having to add at least one extra table to your JOINs in order to retrieve information that is part of the surrogate key.

Two additional advantages of a surrogate key:

1. Many frameworks *require* the use of an integer primary key field.
2. If you are binding your records to any kind of user interface control (inputs on a web page, for example), it's considerably easier to attach a single value to the control for identification purposes than it is to encode and decode multiple columns.

Comment: Why add another table when using an auto-incremement PK and the surrogate key as a candidate key? I have given up on /not/ having a single-"PK" -- although SQLite *always* provides a ROWID aka "int PK" -- but yet find the information can still be encoded in the model with appropriate constraints, at the "expense" of another [candidate/covering] index which may be "cheaper" in terms of reducing fragmentation upon insert. If the candidate index de-normalizes the table then it was *never* a valid candidate for a [surrogate] PK to begin with...

Comment: Bill of materials with Product, Sub-Assembly, Component.  In Sub-Assembly, (ProductID, AssemblyName) is unique.  If you use this as the PK and the FK in Component, you can find Component usage by Product using only Component.  If, instead, you use a surrogate integer primary key, you must JOIN Sub-Assembly (or use a sub-query technique) to get that information.

Comment: Thank you for the concise answer.  The surrogate does appeal more right now because most of my queries probably won't be based on the key (but rather on attributes, e.g. score).  Although, the construction of the database and edits seems like more work and queries may take longer.